# How to position button at bottom of window with expanding content

Tags: html, css

Going to try explain this the best I can.

I want the submit button to always be at the bottom of the page. Now I know this can be achieved with `position: absolute, bottom` etc but there's a catch.

If the content height is less than the wrapping div height, I want the button to display at the bottom of the window if that makes sense?

If the content is longer than the wrapping div height then display at the bottom OF the content, not the window.

Here is a [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/Lu3am0Lo/1/) to show an example of the second condition working - I need help with the first condition

```
.container {
  height: 400px;
  width: 400px;
  background: red;
  overflow: scroll;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

li {
  height: 100px;
  background: blue;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  color: white;
}

button {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  background: black;
  height: 40px;
  color: white;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this is the easiest solution for you: https://jsfiddle.net/7wsrv6z7/

And to be clear, *my* `.wrapper` should go inside your `.container`

## EDIT

Merged with your example: https://jsfiddle.net/Lu3am0Lo/5/

```
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html, body {
  height:100%;
  margin:0;
}

.wrapper {
  padding-bottom:100px;
  min-height:100%;
  background:#fff;
  position:relative;
}

p {
  background:#eee;
}

.wrapper button {
  position:absolute;
  bottom:20px;
  right:20px;
  border-radius:40px;
  background:purple;
  color:#fff;
  padding:10px;
  border:none;
  transition:.2s;
}

.wrapper button:hover {
  padding: 10px 20px;
}

<div class="wrapper">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Unde facilis deserunt voluptates. Ratione quis, a quod, non impedit, earum minima nam asperiores ut sequi rem. Ullam error quia numquam eveniet dicta earum soluta dolor esse ea vel! Ipsum, sapiente, totam.</p>

  <p>lorem300</p>

  <button>SEND</button>
</div>
```

Comment: This is exactly it - I've modified your fiddle to this: https://jsfiddle.net/7wsrv6z7/1/ 

Simply remove and add content and you'll see the solution. Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

One idea you could try is to keep the button outside of the container div and specify a max-width and height for overflowing purposes

See here: https://jsfiddle.net/Lu3am0Lo/2/ for the overflow and https://jsfiddle.net/Lu3am0Lo/3/ if the list doesn't overflow

```
.container {
  max-height: 400px;
  max-width: 400px;
  background: red;
  overflow: scroll;
}
```

EDIT: updated fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/Lu3am0Lo/4/

Comment: I'm getting 404's on those JSFIDDLE links man? I'll add the code you've suggested.

Comment: @Filth Don't know why that is, edited the answer now it should be working

Comment: Very close here and I tried moving the button outside of the container div however, in the actual solution it's within an overlay so if I move it outside of the containing div, it will be floating around on the page. The other thing is, I can't use max-height as it's in an overlay - the height must be fixed... very tricky

Comment: @Filth I've added an extra div with a specific height and then the list attaches under it, that might help

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming from your code that you're using bootstrap. If so you could use the 'sticky footer' idea which (by using margin on the body) always keeps the button at the bottom of the page.

view-source:https://getbootstrap.com/examples/sticky-footer/

https://getbootstrap.com/examples/sticky-footer/sticky-footer.css

Also it obviously doesn't need to be in a footer, just any div and create your own CSS class for it (like they have done with the 'footer' class).

Comment: Sorry mate, this isn't what I'm after. Using position absolute doesn't fix what I'm after. If you check out the jsfiddle and maybe read the question again you might get a better understanding.

Comment: Hi yea I read it a bit too quick and missed out part of a line it seems, apologises. I was going to suggest using jQuery height as a possibility but I see you've got it sorted.

Comment: I thought of using that or media queries targeting the height of the content but the solution I have seems good considering I'm after a CSS fix! Thanks man

Comment: Yea it's a good choice. It's always a win when you can stick to just CSS!

Answer (score 0):

Check if the contents of the container are larger than the container - then add a class depending on this:

jQuery

```
$(document)ready(function(){
if ($('ul').height() > 400 ){
$('button').addClass('relative');
} else {
$('button').addClass('absolute');
}
});
```

CSS

```
.absolute {
  position:absolute;
  bottom:0;
}

.relative {
  position:relative!important;
  bottom:0;
  }
```